# Relation between $\textbf{E}$ and $\textbf{H}$ field for TM wave

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electric-fields, classical-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations

My book (*Nanoscale Energy Transport & Conversion* by Gang Chen, pg. 173) considers the following scenario of a TE wave reflecting at an interface:

[image]

It says the incident $\bf{E}$ field is:
$$\textbf{E}_{\parallel i}exp\left[-i\omega\left(t-\frac{n_1xcos\theta_i+n_1zcos\theta_i}{c_0}\right)\right]$$

and that we can obtain

$$ H_i=\frac{n_1}{\mu c_0}E_{\parallel i}$$

from a Maxwell equation. ***How is this result obtained?***

I assume we use

$$ \nabla \times \textbf{E} =-\frac{\partial \textbf{B}}{\partial t}$$

but

$$ \nabla \times \textbf{E} = \left( \frac{\partial E_x}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial E_z}{\partial x} \right)\hat{\textbf{y}}$$

and the the components $E_x$ and $E_z$ are unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those components are not unknown—in fact in linear media $\mathbf E_\text i$ is going to be perpendicular to $\mathbf k_\text i$ as shown in your figure.

It looks like the author has done something very strange with the actual components of their $\mathbf k$-vector; I would state that given the diagram you have, if the $+x$-direction is away from the interface and the $+z$-direction is otherwise in the direction of $\mathbf k_\text i$ as you have shown, then the right-handed $+y$-direction is into the plane of the figure, we have $\mathbf k_\text i = (-\cos\theta_\text i, 0, +\sin\theta_\text i),$ and then in somewhat more detail we have $$\mathbf E = E_0 ~\begin{bmatrix}\sin\theta_\text i\\ 0\\ \cos\theta_\text i\end{bmatrix}~\exp\left[-i\omega\left(t - \frac{-n_1 x \cos\theta_\text i + n_1 z \sin\theta_\text i}{c_0}\right)\right],$$notice the minus sign appearing by $n_1 x$.

Then indeed we can compute $\nabla \times\mathbf E$ to find
$$
\nabla\times\mathbf E = -i\omega \frac{n_1}{c_0} E_0\begin{bmatrix}0\\-\cos^2\theta_\text i -\sin^2\theta_\text i\\0\end{bmatrix}~\exp\left[-i\omega\left(t - \frac{-n_1 x \cos\theta_\text i + n_1 z \sin\theta_\text i}{c_0}\right)\right],
$$
and of course the quantity inside the column vector there simplifies to just $(0,-1,0).$ The time integral effectively divides by $-i\omega$ leading to $$
\begin{align}\mathbf B &= -\int dt~\nabla\times \mathbf{E}\\
&=-\frac{-i\omega}{-i\omega}\frac{E_0 n_1}{c_0} ~\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}~\exp\left[-i\omega\left(t - \frac{-n_1 x \cos\theta_\text i + n_1 z \sin\theta_\text i}{c_0}\right)\right]\\
&=\frac{E_0 n_1}{c_0} ~\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}~\exp\left[-i\omega\left(t - \frac{-n_1 x \cos\theta_\text i + n_1 z \sin\theta_\text i}{c_0}\right)\right],
\end{align}$$and then in linear media we have $\mathbf H = \mathbf B/\mu,$ hence $$\|\mathbf H\| = \frac{n_1}{\mu c_0}\|\mathbf E\|.$$Note that we haven't used the fact that there exists an interface yet—this is a completely general relation holding for all plane waves in linear media, not just ones that happen to be in a certain plane and happen to be heading towards an interface.

Comment: Your B field is polarized in the negative y-direction (into the screen). Shouldn't it be pointing in the positive y-direction (out of the screen)?

Comment: I'm saying this based on the figure - the B field is positive out of the screen, in the positive y-direction. Your B field seems to violate right hand rule?

Comment: @Drew You are correct that the sign was wrong; I have corrected it.